# Spark 3.3.0 code on EKS failing with java.lang.ClassCastException: java.time.LocalDate cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-eks

I'm using:

- Spark: `3.3.0`
- Scala: `2.13.5`

Below line of code is **working** fine in my **local** intellij but **failing** on **EKS** with error -

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: > java.time.LocalDate cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Code:

```scala
val listOfDates: List[Date] = 
  cgDatesDf
    .filter(cgDatesDf("cgDatecol") < lit(bs_date.toString).cast("Date"))
    .select(col("bs_date"))
    .collect
    .map(f => f.getDate(0))
    .toList
    .takeRight(1)
```

Here,

```
bs_date is equal to 2021-09-30
```

cgDatesDf is Dataframe having below values -

```
+----------------+
|convertedDatecol|
+----------------+
|      2016-08-31|
|      2016-09-30|
|      2016-10-31|
|      2021-08-31|
|      2021-09-30|
|      2021-10-31|
|      2021-11-30|
|      2021-12-31|
|      2022-01-31|
|      2022-06-30|
+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is due to the mismatch between the types `java.time.LocalDate` and `java.sql.Date` in your code.

To resolve this, you need to convert the **LocalDate** objects to `java.sql.Date` objects explicitly.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
val bs_date: LocalDate = LocalDate.parse("2021-09-30")

val listOfDates: List[Date] = cgDatesDf
  .filter(cgDatesDf("convertedDatecol") < lit(bs_date.toString).cast("date"))
  .select(col("convertedDatecol"))
  .collect
  .map(f => Date.valueOf(f.getAs[LocalDate](0)))
  .toList
  .takeRight(1)
```

UPDATE (June 30th, 2023)

Can you try the following code too ?

```
import java.sql.Date
import java.time.LocalDate
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val bs_date: LocalDate = LocalDate.parse("2021-09-30")

val listOfDates: List[LocalDate] = cgDatesDf
  .filter(cgDatesDf("convertedDatecol") < lit(bs_date.toString).cast("date"))
  .select(col("convertedDatecol"))
  .collect
  .map(f => f.getAs[Date](0).toLocalDate)
  .toList
  .takeRight(1)
```

Comment: Thank you @yaoviametepe.    I tried this but that one fails on my local intellij also with reverse error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Date cannot be cast to java.time.LocalDate

Comment: @Anand I updated my answer, give a try to the new code please.

Comment: Thanks @yaoviametepe. That code would created List[LocalDate] but we need to create List[Date] only.

Comment: I tested the new code posted on June 30th, 2023 and that to fails with same error - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.time.LocalDate cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Comment: Hi @yaoviametepe     Any idea about this?